# Google Places Handling Locality of null (Google Android API)

Tags: android, google-places-api

Sometimes Google Places gives null for locality -

an example is: "Rajiv Gandhi International Airport Shamshabad, Hyderabad, Telangana 500409, India"

if I retreive this location through AutoCompletePlace and then use the Longitude and Latitude, I get the locality as null. How do I handle this?

Maybe I'm wrong in the first place in assigning the Place's latitude and Longitude to a Location and trying to revere GeoCode? Is there some simpler way of getting city name from a Place object?

Comment: Hey, What do you use for getting Google Places? like PHP websevices from Google or native support in Android ?

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi native Android API

Comment: You can get any place details by passing particular PLACE ID. You will have to get place id from auto complete list. pass it to Place Detail. you will get the result. i have implemented the same thing by Google Webservice.
Even You can get via two parameters in it like "locality" and "administrative_area_level_2"

Comment: @GulnazGhanchi - plesae see my comment, the Place object has null for locality...